# Modifying appSettings "file" attribute at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, app-config, configurationmanager

```
        string appConfPath = Directory.GetParent(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)).FullName;
        string fullPath = appConfPath + "\\Local\\RandFolder\\ThisOne\\application.settings.xml";
        var config =       ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);


        config.AppSettings.File = fullPath;
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Password", "djydyjdjtdtyjddj");
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        var temp = config.AppSettings;
```

I am currently trying to set the "file" attribute of my appSettings configuration and reference XML's included settings at runtime. I am unable to do this before compile because the XML settings file will change based on the local machines settings.

However, after making the above changes, the temp variable only contains the "Password" item and is unable to retrieve the other settings located in the included file path. I know the file attribute is being set but for some reason the referenced setting are still hidden. The application.settings.xml file looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="ServerLocation" />
  <add key="PerforceURI" value="yuhsgbyluvgblsg" />
</appSettings>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So why dont you use a UserSetting instead?

Comment: If the file is going to change per user, I don't think app.settings is the correct place to put this file location. It should be part of a user profile (in case that you are storing your user somewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't try to critique what you are doing, but provide you with a simple explanation of what you are seeing.

`ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection` refreshes the section in the `Configuration` instance used by the `static ConfigurationManager`. It does not effect the `Configuration` instance you created by calling `OpenExeConfiguration`; for that to occur you would need to call `OpenExeConfiguration` again.